# Why is SQL AG failover not working when service restarted on new primary?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I have all the default WSFC and AG settings. Sync and auto-failover mode.

AG has 2 nodes: Node1 & Node2

Node1 is primary.

I restarted the sql server service on Node1 which resulted in failover to Node2.

Then, I restarted the sql server service on Node2. But it didn't result  in failover to Node1.

Why is SQL AG failover not working when I restarted the sql service on new primary (Node2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is SQL AG failover not working when I restarted the sql service on new primary (Node2)?

By default you've hit the number of failovers in the time period (N-1 number of failovers, where N is the number of nodes in 6 hours). Since the number of failovers has hit the maximum, it will not failover until the time period has elapsed.

This is all available in the cluster log as well, it will tell you the same thing and should be the first source of truth as to what the cluster is doing.

Comment: Where is this setting please? Because the setting I can see is that limits number of restarts.

Comment: It's a setting of the resource group. You can either use the GUI to open the properties of the group, or you can use the get-clustergroup powershell command.

Comment: In the UI I can see that the limit is for number of restarts and not for number of failovers.

Comment: You're not looking at where I stated, you're looking at a resource, not a group.

Comment: Ah you mean on the role - I see that now.